# jQuery returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a really basic problem

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var v= input_value(this,'validate_code');
    alert(v);
}

function input_value(form, name){
    var emptyFields = $(":input").filter(function() {
            if(this.name == name) {
            alert(this.value);
                return this.value;  
                }
    });
}
```

Why does `alert(this.value)` show the real value and `alert(v)` shows 'undefined' ?

Comment: Your `input_value()` function does not return anything. Therefore, `v` will always be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function you pass to `filter` will not make the outer function `input_value` return. The return statement inside the callback is only used to to decide whether to keep the element or not.

If you really want to get the empty fields, you would have to negate the value:

```
var emptyFields = $(":input").filter(function() {
    return !this.value;  
});
```

The question is, what do you want `v` to be?